# "Trick" AeroFS to synchronize outside AeroFS folder without symbolic links

Tags: sync, symbolic-link

I am trying to have a backup copy of my laptop files using AeroFS.

AeroFS creates a folder in your home directory (similar to Dropbox) and syncs anything inside of it.

I would like to sync folders outside of the AeroFS folder such as Pictures, Documents, etc... I have tried using symbolic links, but AeroFS ignores them.

Is there another way to achieve this? A mount perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way: use bind mounts.

For every folder you wish to sync create a folder in AeroFS folder with similar name  (`user` - your user name, `folder` - the name of the folder you want to sync):

```
mkdir /home/user/AeroFS/folder
```

Edit `/etc/fstab`:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Add the following line for every folder you wish to sync with AeroFS:

> /home/user/folder   /home/user/AeroFS/folder   none   bind   0   0

Run:

> sudo mount -a

And you're done.